# Заменить регуляркой все img на содержание alt

Tags: php, preg_replace

Добрый день!

Помогите решить проблему. Есть текст:

```
$text = 'первый<img class="smiles" alt="0&amp;#8419;" src="k.com/images/emoji/003020E3.png">второй<img class="smiles" alt="&amp;#9804;" src="k.com/images/emoji/264C.png">' ;
```

Мне нужно заменить все теги img на содержание атрибута alt. Т.е. в итоге должно получиться

```
'первый0&amp;#8419;второй&amp;#9804;'
```

Делаю такое выражение:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode(preg_replace("/<img(.*)alt=\"(.*)\" src=\"(.*)\"(.*)\>/i","$2", $text)) ;
```

Но результат `первый&amp;#9804;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая группа .* взяла в себя все промежуточные теги, можно заменить "." на "[^>]"

```
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode(preg_replace("/<img([^>]*)alt=\"([^\"]*)\" src=\"([^\"]*)\"([^>]*)\>/i","$2", $text)) ;
```